# Knowing $\exp(i\pi) = -1$, can we find out the value of $\pi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, pi

We know $\exp(i\pi) = -1$ or $e^{i\pi} = -1$.
Can we solve for this infinite polynomial in $\pi$ to obtain the value of $\pi$?
We already know the value of $e$ from two methods:
$e = \exp(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots$
or from:
$ e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} $
So we should in theory be able to solve for the other unknown $\pi$.
We can also try:
$\log(-1) = i\pi$
But it is weird that:
$\log(1 + (-2)) = (-2)-\frac{(-2)^2}{2}+\frac{(-2)^3}{3}-\frac{(-2)^4}{4} + \cdots$
doesn't look like $i\pi$, whatever else it could be made in to.

Comment: Your formula $\log(1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{3}-\ldots$ converges only when $|u|\leq1$, so plugging in $-2$ wont work. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

Comment: Taking lagorithms in the complex numbers always must be done very carefully.

Comment: Use $\exp'=\exp$ to prove that $(\exp^{-1}(z))'=1/z$ which gives that $\exp^{-1}(-1)=4 \int_1^{(1+i)/\sqrt2}  \frac{dz}z$ which is given by a rapidly convergent power series

Comment: You could use lagrange inversion to solve $-1=\exp(x\pi)$ for $x$.

Comment: "So we should, in theory, be able to solve for the other unknown ${\pi}$" - be careful with statements like this. It's not true in general that you can always solve for unknowns. Being able to do so in this case still requires justification

Answer (score 3):

I would say take real or imaginary part, then try to solve.  For example, define $\pi$ as the least positive zero of $\sin(x)$ and use the Taylor series for $\sin$.

Even better is $\tan(\pi/4) = 1$ and use the series for $\arctan$ evaluated at $1$:

$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7} +\dots
$$
This converges slowly, but it converges.

Comment: I'm not sure that the Leibniz series is really "even better" than looking for zeroes of $\sin$ using its power series. Finding $\pi/4$ to precision $1/N$ using the Leibniz series requires about $N$ arithmetic operations, whereas I think the power series method can do with a number of operations that's polynomial in $\log N$.

Comment: It's also worth saying explicitly in this answer that "the least positive zero of $\sin x$" corresponds exactly to "the first positive value for $t$ where the imaginary part of $\exp(it)$ changes sign", and "the Taylor series for $\sin$" is exactly what we get by inserting $it$ into the series expansion of $\exp$ and ignoring terms that don't contribute to the imaginary part. So that suggestion is precisely what the OP was trying to make work!

Answer (score 0):

$$\exp(i\pi) = 1+i\pi-\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \cdots = -1$$

we get for the real part:

1. $\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \cdots = 2$
   giving $\pi \approx 2 $
2. $\frac{\pi^2}{2} - \frac{\pi^4}{24} + \cdots = 2$
   giving $\pi^2 = \left|{\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}}}{-1/12}}\right| = 
   \left|{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}}}{-1/12}}\right| = 6.93, \pi \approx 2.63$
3. $\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \frac{\pi^4}{24} - \frac{\pi^6}{720}  \cdots = 2$
   $\cdots$

Might take a while, but converges to $\pi$ oscillating and meandering like a river over the complex plane, but you can prove that the oscillations dies down as we go further down the line.

As far as the logarithmic one:
    $\log(-1) = i\pi$
has conditional sequence:
    $(−2)−\frac{(−2)^2}{2}+\frac{(−2)^3}{3}−\frac{(−2)^4}{4} + \cdots$
We know in theory a conditional converging series can be made to converge to any number.
Usually we think that it converges only to a real number but in this case it is a bit weird, $i\pi$, but useless information if we want to calculate the value of $\pi$.
Of course, Archimedes had smarter ideas – if you bound the circle between two squares (one from inside and one from outside) and take the average of the two: $\pi \approx \frac{4+2\sqrt{2}}{2} = 3.41$, just 90% there in one shot and gets better with pentagon, hexagon etc.